# open a thumbnail in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'am new and my brain is burning

My problem is this that visit I have a website lemonx.biz.

As you see I have made there 4 frames displaying small shoes of zara hermes and puma.

When the user clicks on the small thumbnails which are in folder `images/zara/thumbnals/1.png` showing zara puma and hermes shoes a new window tab opens displaying the larger version of the thumbnail from `images/zara/1.png` image in a div using html javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your images in anchor tags with an `href` pointing to the larger version of the image and `target="_blank"`.

EDIT: As per your updated instructions.

Instead of linking directly to the image, link to `next.html#name_of_image.jpg`. Then, when next.html is loaded, execute javascript to populate the target div with the appropriate image.

e.g:

```
<!--Include a placeholder image in your HTML in the target div...-->
<div id="target_div">
    <img id="target_img" style="display: none;" src=""/>
</div>

<!--...And populate it on page load with Javascript.-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() 
    {
        if (location.hash) //Only do this if there's an actual hash value.
        {
            var imgPath = 'path/to/images/directory/'; //Build the path to the images directory.
            var imgName = location.hash.substring(1); //Get the name of the image from the hash and remove the #.
            document.getElementById('target_img').src = imgPath+imgName; //Update the src of the placeholder image with the path and name of the real one.
            document.getElementById('target_img').style.display = 'inline'; //Now that it has a valid source, reveal it to the viewer.
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i have done that it works but i have a page next.html in this page i have a div i want to open the clicked thumbnail in next.html in the specific div

Comment: dear aaron what ur code will do is that i have 100s of pics and with all of the pics i have to attach an html and in that every html i have to embed javascript code this is not the solution i need some thing dynamic

Comment: No, you have one html file that reads a hash value dynamically generated by the same script that's generating your thumbnail images on the previous page.